# Redirect when user clicks on an image

Tags: images, forms, input

I want to make it so that when a user clicks on an image in my site, they are redirected to a specific page. I WAS using a submit button for the redirect, but I want to replace it with a custom-designed icon which I have saved as a png.

Here's what I used to have:

```
    <form method='post' id='back_button' action=''>
        <p class='form-submit'>
            <input name='back_button' type='submit' id='back_button' class='submit button' value= 'Go Back' />
        </p>
    </form>
```

In `functions.php`, I have this hooked up like so:

```
if( isset($_POST['back_button'])) redirect_to_team_page(myapp_get_team_uri($_GET['team_id']));
```

I want to update the back button so that it displays as a `.png`. I changed my `<input>` to be an image type, like this:

```
    <form method='post' id='back_button' action=''>
        <p class='form-submit'>
           <input name='back_button' type='image' id='back_button' src='back.png'/>
        </p>
    </form>
```

When I do this, I can't seem to get the form to submit anymore. There must be a better approach, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much better way. I'm using an < a > tag - which I should have been doing all along!

```
    <a href='/my-page/'>
        <div class='back_button'>
            <img id='back_button' class='responsive-img' src='back.png'/>
        </div>
    </a>
```

I'm not sure why I was so stuck on using a form. This is much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ids with the same name and the form gets broken, always provide different ids on a page:

```
<form method='post' id='back_button_form' action=''>
    <p class='form-submit'>
       <input name='back_button_img' type='image' id='back_button_img' src='back.png'/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing the id's does not help. It actually does work with the 2 identical lD's and `<input type='submit'/>` instead of the `<input type='image'/>`

Comment: 2 identical ids is wrong in html.

Comment: I fixed the IDs, but that doesn't fix the bug that I have in my site

Comment: Why don’t you just place the url in the action= then?